# Include a DLL -- and the dlls it depends on -- to a project

Tags: c#, dll

currently I am working on `myDLL.dll`. But `myDLL.dll` needs to include another Dll: `D:\their.dll`. But `their.dll` depends on a couple of other Dlls (`D:\other1.dll`, `D:\other2.dll`).

I have included `their.dll` into my project (as project reference)

```
<Reference Include="theirDLL">
  <HintPath>D:\their.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

And thus, `their.dll` is used in all projects which use `myDLL.dll`.

But I don't know how to include the other dlls, so that they are copied in the same path as `myDLL.dll` and `their.dll` during compiling.

At the moment I use pre-build events to copy the other dlls into the projects which need `myDll.dll` (and therefore `their.dll`). But this is a pain.

Any suggestions?

Best regards,
HarryKane

Answer (score 0):

Add each `.dll` file to your project and (assuming you are developing in Visual Studio) then under `solution explorer -> properties` of each `.dll file`, select `copy local` and set the value to `true`, then each necessary `.dll` will be copied to the bin folder when compiled.

Comment: Hi Ryan, the `other.dlls` will be copied into the same directory as `their.dll`, and thus, `myDLL.dll` should be fine. But when other projects in the solution reference onto myDLL.dll project, then the `other.dlls` are not copied. How do I get them into the other projects, where myDLL.dll (together with `their.dll` and the `other.dll` are needed).

Comment: @HarryKane If all these projects are contained in the same solution file, you should be able to reference the .dll files from each project and still have them copy local into the bin folder and they should resolve.

Comment: hmmm ... I hoped there is a way, that I only have to reference the external dlls (`their` and `other`) in the `myDLL.dll` project while the projects of my solution just have to reference `myDLL.dll` project and get all dlls automatically.

Comment: @HarryKane You should be able to do that, as long as all the dlls are published into the bin folder, you can reference the externals in myDLL and just add a reference to myDLL in each project.